# Exit from doing something every x seconds

Tags: java, android

Hello everyone I'm trying to stop a method from doing something every 6 seconds once a certain criteria is met. I figured to use finish() but it redirects me back to the previous
layout and still shows the toast message every 6 seconds. Here's the run method

```
protected static final long TIME_DELAY = 6000;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view);

        mHandler.post(updateTextRunnable);
    }

    Runnable updateTextRunnable=new Runnable(){  
        public void run() {       

            if(//Criteria==true){
                     message();
                         finish(); 
                }
                  mHandler.postDelayed(this, TIME_DELAY);  
                 }  
         };  

public void message(){

        Toast.makeText(this, "Found",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

How can I have it once the the criteria is met exit the run but still stay on the same layout

Comment: Please if you make a question with a source code make sure it's well formatted. This way it's quite unreadable. By the way to answer the question, you should put the `mHandler.postDelayed(this, TIME_DELAY); ` in the else branch of your `if`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only invoke your postDeleyed call if the criteria is false (i.e. add an else statement as below).

```
if(//Criteria==true){    
    message();   
    finish();  
} else {    
    mHandler.postDelayed(this, TIME_DELAY);   
}
```

Comment: wow I can't believe I missed that, just mean I was staring at the code for far too long and it was there right in my face thanks just needed some different eyes. I'll check it now